# difference between scan and execute function in Elastic Search DSL

Tags: elasticsearch, python-3.5, elasticsearch-dsl

So i am using `elasticsearch_dsl` to search & query data by *index* which i have on my *localhost*.

```
from pprint import pprint
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch('http://localhost:9200')
s = elasticsearch_dsl.Search(using=es, index='your_index_name')

result1 = s.execute() #using the execute method
result2 = s.scan() # using the scan method

pprint(result1.to_dict()) #check data.txt file for the output which prints only the initial 10 entries of data 

count1 = 0
for i in result1:
    print(i.Author) # will print Author name. look data.txt
    #print(i._index) #gives error
    count1+=1
print count1 #prints 10 i.e. only initial 10 entries 
count2 = 0

for i in result2:
    count2+=1
print count2 #prints 1016 i.e. all the 1016 entries
```

I get the following result [data.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WYtzg6XWnHK4bcfy__QhikNpbwcKkeiP/view?usp=sharing) , but this doesn't print the whole data , it just prints the initial 10 entries of data , where as it actually has 1016 entries . My questions :-

> 1.) difference between scan and execute function
>
> 2.) like `execute` has `to_dict()` function to print the raw data , is there any similar function for `scan` method to print the data?
>
> 3.) why does `execute()` gives only the initial 10 entries ?
>
> 4.) Also if you look at the *data.txt* file , when i want to get lets say *Author Name* , it has a keyword `Author` , so i can access it by running a loop and doing `print(i.Author)` , but i am unable to access `_index` value .`print(i._index)` gives an error . how to get this value ?

I have been trying really hard and have done a lot of googling and have played a lot with my code , but still i am unable to get how this is working . I would be glad if anyone could help.

Answer (score 4):

To best understand the difference, I recommend you have a look at Elasticsearch itself. `execute` (or just iterating over a `Search` object) just runs `_search` API (0). `scan` on the other hand is a wrapper around the `scan/scroll` API (1) which is an "export" API designed to unload all of your data from Elasticsearch, not just the top hits.

You can access all metadata like `_id` or `_index` via the `meta` attribute, so: `i.meta.id` and `i.meta._index`

0 - http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html

1 - http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html